# How to keep medians and whiskers (and remove the rest) from a boxplot using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to keep only the medians and whiskers from a boxplot (removing the boxes itself) and although I found a way to do almost something (not 100% what I want) with base R... I do not know how to do it with `ggplot2`.

Base R:

```
boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, 
        boxlty = 0,
        boxfill = 0)
```

[image]

ggplot2:

```
p <- ggplot(InsectSprays, aes(x=spray, y=count)) + 
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar",
               width = 0.15) + 
  geom_boxplot()

p <- p + geom_jitter(aes(fill = spray), shape = 21, color = "black", size=5) +  
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(color='black'),
        plot.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        legend.position="none") + ylab("Counts")
p
```

[image]

However, I am quite far away from what I want, cause as I said at the beginning, I want to remove the box and keep the median and whiskers. And if possible, extend the whiskers till the median as I tried to modify in the following screenshot:

[image]

Does anybody how to do it with `ggplot2`?

Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach below is a bit clunky, but it seems like it works.  It uses `stat_boxplot()` and the its constructed variables `after_stat(ymin)`, `after_stat(ymax)` and `after_stat(middle)`.  I use one call to `stat_boxplot()` to make the whisker bars and one to make the median line.

```r
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(cyl), y=qsec)) + 
  stat_boxplot(aes(ymin = after_stat(ymin), ymax = after_stat(ymax)), geom="errorbar", width=.25) + 
  stat_boxplot(aes(ymin = after_stat(middle), ymax = after_stat(middle)), geom="errorbar", linewidth=2, width=.25)  + 
  geom_point(aes(colour=as.factor(cyl)), position=position_jitter(width=.25)) + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>